# how to pass ComponentController to a controller

Tags: playframework-2.6

I have a controller. I want to pass a DAO component `userRepo` to it

```
class UserController @Inject()(userRepo: Repository[User,Integer],cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc){...}
```

I am hooking compile time DI as follows:

```
class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with CassandraRepositoryComponents {

  lazy val applicationController = new controllers.UserController(userRepository)
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)

  override def router: Router = new Routes(
    httpErrorHandler,
    applicationController,
    assets
  )
}
```

**Question 1** - My issue is that I don't know what to pass as `ControllerComponent`

**Question 2** - I am getting the following error `missing parameter meta:AssetsMetaData` for `lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)`

**Question 3** - I suppose I am not using Routes correctly as well. I can see that IDE is displaying a potential error `cannot resolve constructor`

```
  override def router: Router = new Routes(
    httpErrorHandler,
    applicationController,
    assets
  )
```

I am following the following tutorial but as it is based on `Play 2.4`, it will probably not run in 2.6. How could I make the code above work in `Play 2.6`?

http://manuel.kiessling.net/2016/01/17/compile-time-cassandra-injection-in-play-2-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to 1 - `BuiltInComponentsFromContext` has an instance of `ControllerComponents`

Answer to 2 - Used `assets` defined in `BuiltInComponentsFromContext`.

Answer to 3 - The routes file expects that all the controllers are passed to it. In my case. I wasn't passing all the controllers.

Full code

```
class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with CassandraRepositoryComponents
  with HttpFiltersComponents
  with controllers.AssetsComponents
  with CSRFComponents{


  lazy val userRepositoryController = new controllers.UserController(userRepository, controllerComponents) //answer 1
  lazy val homeController = new controllers.HomeController(controllerComponents, csrfAddToken,csrfCheck) //answer 3. create all controllers and pass it to Routes below
  //AtomicCounter is application's class, not Play's class to it is instantiated explicitly in the loader.
  lazy val countController = new controllers.CountController(controllerComponents,new AtomicCounter())
  lazy val asyncController = new controllers.AsyncController(controllerComponents, actorSystem)

  lazy val userWSRoutes = new WSRouters.User.UserRouter(userRepositoryController) //I am using SIRD router, so creating them here

  lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController,userWSRoutes, countController,asyncController, assets) //answer to 2


}
```